# How to strech image inside the div box using CSS?

Tags: css

I would like to display an image to stretch inside the class with a name with `.box a` and the bottom of that .box should be a 75px div height where I can display name and position. I have tried the below image it is not stretching fully throughout .box class. What else do I need to change in CSS.

```
                   <div className="row">
                    <div className="squads">
                        <div className="box a">A
                        <img src="images/test1.png"/>
                            <section className="squaddetails">
                               <span>Test Man</span>
                            </section>
                            <section className="squaddetails">
                               <span>Forward</span>
                            </section>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

//css

```
@media (min-width: 1920px) {
    .squads {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: 400px 400px 400px 400px !important;
        height: 600px !important;
        grid-gap: 10px !important;
        background-color: #fff;
        color: #444;
        margin: 20px 20px 10px 100px !important;
        padding: 20px;
      }
      
      .box {
        background-color: #444;
        color: #fff;
        border-radius: 5px;
        padding: 20px !important;
        font-size: 150%;
        border: solid 2px rgb(48, 27, 165);
      }
    
    .squads > .box img{
        max-width:100% !important;
    }
}
```

Expected display below :

[image]

Current/Actual Display :

[image]

Comment: Can you try by adding: "width:100%; " so code will be like that - ".squads > .box img{  max-width:100% !important; width:100%;  }"

Comment: It will help you ; https://codepen.io/AlissaKennedy/pen/VVmxJX

Answer (score 0):

```css
.squads > .box img{
  max-width:100% !important;
  width:100% !important;
}

@media (min-width: 1920px) {
.squads {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 400px 400px 400px 400px !important;
  height: 600px !important;
  grid-gap: 10px !important;
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #444;
  margin: 20px 20px 10px 100px !important;
  padding: 20px;
}

.box {
  background-color: #444;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 20px !important;
  font-size: 150%;
  border: solid 2px rgb(48, 27, 165);
}

.squads > .box img{
  max-width:100% !important;
}
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="squads">
        <div class="box a">
        <img src= "https://picsum.photos/id/237/200/300"/>
            <section class="squaddetails">
               <span>Test Man</span>
            </section>
            <section class="squaddetails">
               <span>Forward</span>
            </section>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```